# I'm trying to change the text inside the buttons in a Gridview to the string in one of the cells on the same row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is how my gridview looks

[image]

I want to make so the text in the first button is matching the forumname , in this example it should be ssssss and the button below it should be Seinfeld. I'm getting the data from an array that I get from Service that I wrote, then I bind the array to the GridView. I think I should change the button text while the gridview is being created but I don't have any idea how to accomplish that.

Also the gridview is created after typing in a box the forum name you want to find then clicking go.

**Code:**

```
    protected void btgo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        string forumname = tbforumname.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(forumname) == true)
        {
            lberror.Text = "Please enter a forum to search!";
        }

        else  if (ws.GetList(forumname) == null)
            lberror.Text = "didn't found any matching forums!";
        else
        { 
            GridView1.DataSource = ws.GetList(forumname);
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

**Html:**
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyInterface.menu" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="tbforumname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btgo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btgo_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lberror" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Button" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your asp markup

Comment: I'm sorry but what is asp markup exactly?

Comment: show us your html code ( aka asp markup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `asp:TemplateField` inside your gridview for your button, you could try this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="myButton" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ColumnTextName") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

`ColumnTextName` is the name of the forumname column. The button text will be written every time you fill your gridview

**EDIT**

For `ButtonField` try this

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int colText = 1; //the index of the column you want to get the text
        int colButton = 0; //the index of the column of your button
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            (e.Row.Cells[colButton].Controls[0] as Button).Text = e.Row.Cells[colText].Text;
        }            
    }
```

and add this property to the gridview `OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"`

Comment: I posted the asp I have , and what to do in that situation? I don't have TemplateField and I don't use Button rather I use ButtonField and the ID isn't displayed

Comment: Thanks mate! you're legendry it worked perfect for ButtonField !

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView_OnRowCreated or GridView_OnRowDataBound, depending on when you want to set the text, to set the button text using the value of the cell you want.

RowCreated:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcreated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

RowDataBound:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public void GridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button button = e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("myButtonId") as Button;
        Label label = e.Row.Cells[2].FindControl("myLabelId") as Label;
        if(button != null && label != null)
        {
            button.Text = label.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright but it seems to that if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) returns false so it doesn't do the actions that we need. any idea why?

Comment: Since you added asp syntax, looks like you're using a ButtonField, not just an <asp:Button> so you have to change it up. Try adding <asp:ButtonField Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataSourcePropertyToUse")%>' />

Comment: Alright man, I tried to do that but I got an error. so I tried to do the way Enrique  Zavaleta posted on buttonfields and it seems to work fine! this site is awesome.